# Characteristic subgroups of $ SO(4) $

Tags: lie-groups, orthogonal-matrices

There are exactly 3 nontrivial proper normal subgroups of $ SO_4 $. This can be seen by using Goursat's lemma on the double cover $ SU_2 \times SU_2 $ and then noting that only 5 of the 10 normal subgroups in $ SU_2 \times SU_2 $ descend to the quotient $ SO_4 $ (in other words only 5 contain the element $ (-1,-1) $ ). Of these five normal subgroups, two are just the trivial group and all of $ SO_4 $. The remaining groups are the center $ \pm I $ and the groups of left and right isoclinic rotations, respectively, both of which are isomorphic to $ SU_2 $. Are these two copies of $ SU_2 $ characteristic subgroups? (If not then the outer automorphism given by conjugation by a reflection in $ O_4 $ must switch the two copies of $ SU_2 $.)

Also, consider the following. The complex numbers $ \mathbb{C} $ are a 2d real vector space. $ SO_2 $ acts on $ \mathbb{C} $ by rotations. There is a homomorphism $ SO_2 \to U_1 $ given by
$$
\phi \mapsto \phi(1) 
$$
The quaternions $ \mathbb{H} $ are a 4d real vector space. $ SO_4 $ acts on $ \mathbb{H} $ by rotations. There is a map $ R: SO_4 \to SU_2 $ (here $ SU_2 $ is thought of as the group of norm 1 quaternions) given by
$$
R: \phi \mapsto \phi(1)
$$
This map takes the identity to the identity. Is it a group homomorphism? If so is the kernel would have to be $ SU_2 $ by my argument above. But that doesn't seem right. Is there any easy way to see this is not a homomorphism? What nice properties does this map have?

**Question: Are the groups of left and right isoclinic rotations characteristic? Or can they be exchanged by the outer automorphism of $ SO_4 $? Is one of these groups the kernel of the map $ R $? Is $ R $ even a homomorphism?**

Comment: Hint: What happens with the outer automorphisms arising from $O(4)$?

Comment: This doesn't quite answer your question but $ SO_4 $ is double covered by $ SU_2 \times SU_2 $ and the only outer automorphism of $ SU_2 \times SU_2 $ is just the map $ \tau $ switching the two factors (usually each factor $ SU_n $ would have its own outer automorphism but outer automorphisms are trivial for $ n=2 $). Since the kernel $ (-1,-1) $ of the map $ SU_2 \times SU_2 \to SO_4 $ if fixed by $ \tau $ then I think $ \tau $ should descend to the quotient and thus exchange the left $ (q,1) $ and right $ (1,q) $ isoclinic groups of rotations ($ q \in SU_2 $).

Comment: Since $ Out(SO_{2n}) $ is cyclic of order 2 with the nontrivial element coming from conjugation by $ O_{2n} $ then $ \tau $ must coincide with conjugation by something like $ diag(-1,1,1,1) $. However I'm not sure how to see that equality directly.

Comment: There's no need for so much abstraction. Take a left/right isoclinic rotation and conjugate by a reflection. Is the result left/right isoclinic?